# Single node standalone Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Is there any way I can install and use Spark without Hadoop/HDFS on a single node? I just want to try some simple examples and I would like to keep it as light as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.
However it needs hadoop libraries underneath, so download any version of prebuilt spark like,

```
wget http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-1.6.0/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.4.tgz
tar -xvzf spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.4.tgz
cd spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.4/bin
./spark-shell
```

Comment: @AliShakiba , Don't down-vote, if you are not aware of how spark works in first place. Here is something to get you started, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10944